# Add only single space on either side of character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
//case 1
var str = 'x=12';

str = str.replace(/=/g, ' = ');  // str = 'x = 12';

//case 2
var str = 'x =12';

str = str.replace(/ =/g, '= '); // str = 'x = 12';

//case 3
var str = 'x= 12';

str = str.replace(/= /g, ' ='); // str = 'x = 12';
```

I need to check for all 3 cases. If I just use all 3 `replace()` statements above, it adds extra spaces. 
Any better way? (maybe regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do that:

```
/ ?= ?/g
```

You can also use:

```
/\s?=\s?/g
```

Here `\s` matches all white space characters.

It checks if there is a `=` sign with or without a space before and/or after it. The `?` sign checks if the white space character matches zero or one time.

```
str = str.replace(/ ?= ?/g, ' = ');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//case 1
var str = 'x=12';

str.replace(/\s*=\s*/,' = ');  // str = 'x = 12';

//case 2
var str = 'x =12';

str.replace(/\s*=\s*/,' = '); // str = 'x = 12';

//case 3
var str = 'x= 12';

str.replace(/\s*=\s*/,' = '); // str = 'x = 12';
```